# Should I withdraw my paper because review is taking too long?

Tags: publications, journals, editors, journal-workflow, withdraw

I submitted an article to a prestigious journal JCR Q1 about 20 months ago. It took more than 6 months for them to send the article for review. But it was worth it. The reviewers did a good job and decided "major revisions". The EiC was very kind to me and made suggestions for improvement.

However, it has now been 11 months since I submitted the revisions, and I still have not received a decision (the status remains at "with editor"). I have contacted the EiC twice and asked for an update. The first time (6 months after resubmission) she told me that Covid had delayed the process. The second time (10 months after resubmission) she told me that she was still reviewing the revisions and was happy with everything at the moment, that she thought the article was good, but required a few more weeks. She told me he didn't think any further rounds of revisions were needed. But I still haven't heard back.

I also have 2 submitted articles in that same journal that have not been sent for peer review yet (8 months since submission).

I do not come from a field where such delays are common, although the turnaround time for this journal is particularly high (the other published articles had an average turnaround time of a year before covid).

Considering that (1) this is one of the few journals specific to my (sub, sub)field, and (2) the editor seems favorably disposed toward the revised article, is it worth waiting, or should I withdraw my article(s)?

### Update (15th, December 2021)

The Editor in Chief, although later than she predicted, finally informed me of her decision: The article submitted some time ago has been accepted and the other two most recent articles have been sent for peer rreview. It was worthy to wait.

---

---

Comment: Do you have a need for quick action? Or just worried about the delay?

Comment: @Buffy I am applying to postdocs, but I am specially worried about the delay

Comment: If applying for postdocs: unless there is a strong requirement about "number of published paper", it is almost the same to have a paper from 2020 published or under review. It will not be a deciding factor.
You mention you have 2 other paper under review: maybe those are worthwhile to taken back and submitted to a different journal.

Comment: @EarlGrey Thank you for your comment. So, are you suggesting that I include the "under review" articles in my CV? I was planning not to include them, just in case the information about authorship leaks out (e.g. postdoc evaluators act as reviewers of my articles).

Comment: Just to make sure I got the timeline right, was it roughly a month ago that the editor told you they needed "a few more weeks"?

Comment: @TooTea Yes, it was around 4 weeks ago (4 weeks and 5 days).

Comment: @Naorp97 Blind review is a "best effort" sort of thing, and shouldn't constrain you outside the review process. If you feel that your paper's chances would likely be harmed if your identity as author was revealed then that's a different sort of thing, but otherwise don't bend over backwards to maintain the secrecy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Implicit in your question is the assumption "if I withdraw my paper I will be able to get it published elsewhere faster".

Are you sure that will happen though? It's entirely possible you withdraw it, send it to another journal, they take six months to review and suggest revisions, and then take another six months to review the revision.

Ultimately it's up to you, but the fact that the editor-in-chief of this journal is responsive is, I think, a good sign that you will get a decision eventually.

Answer (score 10):

It is hard to say. My wife had an article in review for 2 years (top journal in our field) and did get published.
Do not withdraw an article with major revisions but rather the other two.

I recommend you talk with your mentor / advisor - they can hopefully give you the best advice for your career / next steps and what is best.

My wife has had manuscripts rejected only to be accepted by other journals. You need to talk to someone in your field and that knows your situation to provide the best advice.