# How long should I wait to contact an Editor-in-Chief if she told me she would contact soon but has not yet done so?

Tags: journals, email, editors, communication, journal-workflow

In another [post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178056/should-i-withdraw-my-paper-because-review-is-taking-too-long), I mentioned that I have been waiting for a decision on a revised article for more than 11 months.

During those months of waiting, I have contacted the Editor-in-Chief (EiC) twice to inquire about the article's status, and she has always told me that I would receive her assessment soon. The last time, 1 1/2 months ago, she told me I would receive a response no later than the following week (to date, I have not received any update).

Understanding that EiCs are busy people, I don't know to what extent it would be *advisable* to email her again now (I fear that my insistence will negatively affect the decision on my article).

Do you think I should contact EiC and send her a friendly reminder, or should I forget it and wait? **How long should I wait to write to her again without becoming a pest?**

Comment: Better not use acronyms that are not generally recognized. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that badgering an editor is going to speed up the process in any way. In fact, when a lot of people do this, it can just slow it down. Yes, they will probably respond, and their response may just be a way to put you off, but the process is still going to be followed.

The decision may not be an individual decision, actually, and editors may need some sign-off, especially in edge cases.

But whether you keep pushing or not, it will still happen when it happens.

Everybody in your situation is anxious. Relax and move on to the next big thing.