# I submitted a paper over a year ago and have not heard back. What should I do?

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, paper-submission, early-career

I submitted a pure mathematics paper (my first paper!) to a journal in September 2020. It is now December 2021 and I have received zero reports. A few months ago I sent an enquiry. I got a response saying that I should hear back soon and that there is a very large backlog due to administrative issues. My thesis adviser told me that this is extremely unusual (I'm not sending it to the Annals). What is the correct protocol for how one should proceed?

Comment: I continuously find it baffling and unprofessional that review times of a year are considered acceptable in pure math. :-(

Comment: Is it just you that wrote it?  If you have a well-known or influential co-author on the paper, they can chase it up a bit more effectively than you can (I am assuming you are a student).

Comment: @Tom Yes, it was just me

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm a pure mathematician and it took a paper of mine 7 months to just get a referee. This is rather unusual, I admit. Depending on the journal and the paper, a two-year wait might be considered in the normal range (esp for a long paper at a very fancy journal)

Comment: It is, unfortunately, not that unusual.

Comment: Your advisor is right:  Over a year is unusual.  It happened to me only once in 35 years.  (I am in mathematics, too.)  As long as the preprint is available, you could list it in your vita as "submitted 2020" or something.

Comment: At least have them verify that they received it.  Occasionally, there is a transmission error, whether postal or over the internet.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I know that it is not unusual. I nevertheless find it callous and disrespectful, primarily to the younger members of our community who rely on getting their papers turned around in a timely manner.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I agree it is not good to keep people waiting. This paper that took 7 months to find a referee went from arXiv to pre-published in about the time I did an entire (long) postdoc. Having it published in a reasonable time would I'm sure have helped in any job/grant applications, were I pursuing them.

Answer (score 32):

> A few months ago I sent an enquiry. I got a response saying that I should hear back soon and that there is a very large backlog of administrative issues.

You *did* hear back. You just did not get a review report.

What to do is a difficult question (see e.g. [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178056/should-i-withdraw-my-paper-because-review-is-taking-too-long)), but in your case there's an easy answer. Ask your thesis advisor and do whatever they say - they are after all much more experienced than you, know the contents of your paper, know the review process of your field, and know what tier of journals to aim for. If they're an author on the manuscript, you'll also need their approval to submit elsewhere, per standard protocol.

Answer (score 15):

They have responded, and there is not much you can do to *force* their hand, especially if they have "a backlog of papers" to choose from. You likely have expedited your process by messaging them already. It could have been lost in the shuffle, assigned to reviewers who are tardy, or the reviewers could be hard to find for your sub-area.

If this paper is particularly important, you may be able to inform them of why. Editors have ways of expediting processes for those who need it. You could potentially skip the queue or get assigned fast and trustworthy reviewers. For example: "I am up for (tenure review)/(dissertation defense) on XYZ. Is it possible to get an estimate of about how long it will take for a response?"

If you are particularly in a rush, you can even threaten to withdraw the paper. Only do this if you *really* would do so and *really* do need a response soon. Some sample text might be: "This timing is extremely important to me, and I may need to withdraw if I cannot have a response by then."

However, this is your first paper - don't rush it. You want a response now, but don't need it. If this journal was your top pick, the best end destination for this article - **do not withdraw because you are impatient.** You have plenty of time to rush articles later. Start your career off right with the best publication(s) you can. The months it takes to get a response will be worth it.

Comment: I am not sure I agree. I submitted a paper when I was a postdoc, heard nothing, and kept quiet about it. Eventually I asked after a year or so, and they had forgotten about it. Later still, I got a single-paragraph rejection. The editor did apologise that it was so late. Unfortunately, my career had ended by then, since postdocs only have a finite duration and you usually need a publication record to get a second one.

Comment: That's a horribly unfortunate circumstance! The most important distinction is that this individual is still in contact with the publisher.  I've clarified to not withdraw *out of impatience*.